# Why I'm getting the error [FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert]?

Tags: solidity, foundry, revert

I am getting these 2 errors (both are EvmError: Revert errors),from my fuzz test contrac for my NFTMarketplace contract.
I think it might be that the fuzz test contract isin't interacting with the NFTMarketplace contract as it should. (but IDK).
Please help.

```
Running 1 test for test/fuzz/NFTMFuzzTests.t.sol:NFTMFuzzTest
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] test_FuzzCreateToken() (gas: 14509)
Logs:
  tokenURI:  baseURI
  price:  11000000000000000

Traces:
  [14509] NFTMFuzzTest::test_FuzzCreateToken()
    ├─ [0] console::log("tokenURI: ", "baseURI\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] console::log("price: ", 11000000000000000 [1.1e16]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::assume(true) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000::listPrice() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← EvmError: Revert
```

```
Running 1 test for test/fuzz/NFTMFuzzTests.t.sol:NFTMFuzzTest
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] test_FuzzExecuteSale() (gas: 5160)
Traces:
  [5160] NFTMFuzzTest::test_FuzzExecuteSale()
    ├─ [0] 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000::getListedToken(1) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← EvmError: Revert
```

here are both contracts for context:
I am using the Foundry framework.

NFTMarketplace.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {console} from "../lib/forge-std/src/console.sol";
import {Counters} from "../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import {Ownable} from "../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import {ERC721URIStorage} from "../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import {ERC721} from "../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is Ownable, ERC721URIStorage {

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    //_tokenIds variable has the most recent minted tokenId
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    //Keeps track of the number of items sold on the marketplace
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;
    //owner is the contract address that created the smart contract
    address payable marketplaceOwner;
    //The fee charged by the marketplace to be allowed to list an NFT
    uint256 public listPrice = 0.01 ether;

     //The structure to store info about a listed token
    struct ListedToken {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable owner;
        address payable seller;
        uint256 price;
        bool currentlyListed;
    }

     //the event emitted when a token is successfully listed
    event TokenListedSuccess (
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address owner,
        address seller,
        uint256 price,
        bool currentlyListed
    );

    //This mapping maps tokenId to token info and is helpful when retrieving details about a tokenId
    mapping(uint256 => ListedToken) public idToListedToken;

    constructor() Ownable(msg.sender) ERC721("NFTMarketplace", "NFTM") {
    marketplaceOwner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {
        revert("Function does not exist");
    }

    function updateListPrice(uint256 _listPrice) public onlyOwner {
        listPrice = _listPrice;
    }

    function getListPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        return listPrice;
    }

    function getListedToken(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (ListedToken memory) {
        return idToListedToken[tokenId];
    }

    function publicGetTokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
        return tokenURI(tokenId);
    }


    function getLatestIdToListedToken() public view returns (ListedToken memory) {
        uint256 currentTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        return idToListedToken[currentTokenId];
    }

    function getListedTokenForId(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (ListedToken memory) {
        return idToListedToken[tokenId];
    }

    function getCurrentToken() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tokenIds.current();
    }

     //The first time a token is created, it is listed here
    function createToken(string memory tokenURI, uint256 price) public payable returns (uint256) {
        //Increment the tokenId counter, which is keeping track of the number of minted NFTs
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();

        //Mint the NFT with tokenId newTokenId to the address who called createToken
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenId);

        //Map the tokenId to the tokenURI (which is an IPFS URL with the NFT metadata)
        _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenURI);

        //Helper function to update Global variables and emit an event
        createListedToken(newTokenId, price);

        return newTokenId;
    }

    function createListedToken(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) private {
        //Make sure the sender sent enough ETH to pay for listing
        require(msg.value == listPrice, "Hopefully sending the correct price");
        //Just sanity check
        require(price > 0, "Make sure the price isn't negative");

        //Update the mapping of tokenId's to Token details, useful for retrieval functions
        idToListedToken[tokenId] = ListedToken(
            tokenId,
            payable(address(this)),
            payable(msg.sender),
            price,
            true
        );

        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
        // _transfer(address(this), marketplaceOwner, tokenId); // maybe this one?

        //Emit the event for successful transfer. The frontend parses this message and updates the end user
        emit TokenListedSuccess(
            tokenId,
            address(this),
            msg.sender,
            price,
            true
        );
    }

    //This will return all the NFTs currently listed to be sold on the marketplace
    function getAllNFTs() public view returns (ListedToken[] memory) {
        uint256 nftCount = _tokenIds.current();
        ListedToken[] memory tokens = new ListedToken[](nftCount);
        uint256 currentIndex = 0;
        uint256 currentId;
        //at the moment currentlyListed is true for all, if it becomes false in the future we will 
        //filter out currentlyListed == false over here
        for(uint256 i=0;i<nftCount;i++)
        {
            currentId = i + 1;
            ListedToken storage currentItem = idToListedToken[currentId];
            tokens[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }
        //the array 'tokens' has the list of all NFTs in the marketplace
        return tokens;
    }

    //Returns all the NFTs that the current user is owner or seller in
    function getMyNFTs() public view returns (ListedToken[] memory) {
        uint256 totalItemCount = _tokenIds.current();
        uint256 itemCount = 0;
        uint256 currentIndex = 0;
        uint256 currentId;
        //Important to get a count of all the NFTs that belong to the user before we can make an array for them
        for(uint256 i=0; i < totalItemCount; i++)
        {
            if(idToListedToken[i+1].owner == msg.sender || idToListedToken[i+1].seller == msg.sender){
                itemCount += 1;
            }
        }

        //Once you have the count of relevant NFTs, create an array then store all the NFTs in it
        ListedToken[] memory items = new ListedToken[](itemCount);
        for(uint256 i=0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
            if(idToListedToken[i+1].owner == msg.sender || idToListedToken[i+1].seller == msg.sender) {
                currentId = i+1;
                ListedToken storage currentItem = idToListedToken[currentId];
                items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
                currentIndex += 1;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    function executeSale(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        uint256 price = idToListedToken[tokenId].price;
        address payable seller = payable(idToListedToken[tokenId].seller);
        require(msg.value == price + listPrice, "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");

        // Transfer the listing fee to the marketplace creator
        payable(marketplaceOwner).transfer(listPrice);

        // Transfer the proceeds from the sale to the seller of the NFT
        seller.transfer(msg.value);

        // Transfer the token to the new owner
        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);

        // Update the details of the token
        idToListedToken[tokenId].currentlyListed = true;
        _itemsSold.increment();
    }

    //We might add a resell token function in the future
    //In that case, tokens won't be listed by default but users can send a request to actually list a token
    //Currently NFTs are listed by default
}
```

NFTMFuzzTests.t.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {NFTMarketplace} from "../../src/NFTMarketplace.sol";
import {DeployNFTMarketplace} from "../../script/DeployNFTMarketplace.s.sol";
import {Counters} from "../../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import {Ownable} from "../../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import {ERC721URIStorage} from "../../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import {ERC721} from "../../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import {Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {console} from "../../lib/forge-std/src/console.sol";
import {Vm} from "../../lib/forge-std/src/Vm.sol";


contract NFTMFuzzTest is Test {
    // Declare a variable to hold the deployed contract
    NFTMarketplace nftMarketplace;

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    uint256 private nonce =  0;

    function beforeEach() public {
        // Initialize the NFTMarketplace contract
        nftMarketplace = new NFTMarketplace();

        // Create a token with a generated URI and price
        string memory tokenURI = generateRandomTokenURI();
        uint256 price = generateRandomPrice();
        (bool success, ) = address(nftMarketplace).call{value: nftMarketplace.listPrice()}(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("createToken(string,uint256)", tokenURI, price)
        );
        require(success, "Failed to create token");

        // Log the listPrice after the token is created
        console.log('listPrice after beforeEach: ', nftMarketplace.listPrice());
    }


    function generateRandomTokenURI() public view returns (string memory) {
        // Generate a unique tokenURI by appending the nonce to a base URI
        return string(abi.encodePacked("baseURI", nonce));
    }

    function incrementNonce() private {
        nonce++;
    }

    function generateRandomPrice() public pure returns (uint256) {
        // Generate a random price greater than listPrice
        return 0.011 ether;
    }

    function test_FuzzCreateToken() public payable {
        // Generate a random tokenURI
        string memory tokenURI = generateRandomTokenURI();

        console.log('tokenURI: ', tokenURI);

        // Generate a random price greater than listPrice
        uint256 price = generateRandomPrice();

        console.log('price: ', price);

        // Ensure that the tokenURI is not empty
        vm.assume(bytes(tokenURI).length > 0);

        // console.log(nftMarketplace.getListPrice());

        // Send the exact amount of Ether required to create a token
        (bool success, ) = address(nftMarketplace).call{value: nftMarketplace.listPrice()}(abi.encodeWithSignature("createToken(string,uint256)", tokenURI, price));
        require(success, "Failed to create token");

        uint256 newTokenId = nftMarketplace.getCurrentToken();
        console.log('newTokenId', newTokenId);

        // Increment the nonce for the next tokenURI generation
        // incrementNonce();
        // console.log('nonce, ', nonce);

        assertTrue(newTokenId > 0, 'New token ID should be greater than 0');
        assertEq(nftMarketplace.publicGetTokenURI(newTokenId), tokenURI, 'Token URI does not match');
    }


    function test_FuzzExecuteSale() public payable {
        // Generate a valid tokenId
        uint256 tokenId = 1;

        // Ensure that the tokenId exists
        vm.assume(nftMarketplace.getListedToken(tokenId).currentlyListed);

        // Calculate the total price
        uint256 totalPrice = nftMarketplace.getListedToken(tokenId).price + nftMarketplace.listPrice();

        // Send the total price in Ether
        (bool success, ) = address(nftMarketplace).call{value: totalPrice}(abi.encodeWithSignature("executeSale(uint256)", tokenId));
        require(success, "Failed to execute sale");

        // Check that the token is no longer listed
        assertFalse(nftMarketplace.getListedToken(tokenId).currentlyListed, 'Token should no longer be listed');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

import {Counters} from "../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

current(counter)

increment(counter)

decrement(counter)

reset(counter)

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/4233

This library has been removed from OpenZeppelin Contracts for version 5.0, but you can find it in version 4.0

**I believe this might be the case, but I'm not sure. Please clearly define which problem you are attempting to solve with these contracts**

Comment: Hi gurwinder singh, thanks for responding the counters file is custom and it works fine.
the problem is that the 2 fuzz tests are failing and IDK why I suspect it's because the Fuzz test contract is not interacting with the NFTMarketplace contract as it should but yet again I'm not sure, maybe the fuzz contract isn't set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

$ forge install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.9.5 --no-commit
Installing openzeppelin-contracts in "C:///evm/lib\openzeppelin-contracts" (url: Some("https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts"), tag: Some("4.9.5"))
Error:
Tag: "4.9.5" not found for repo: "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts"!

$ forge install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts --no-commit
Installing openzeppelin-contracts in "C://evm/lib\openzeppelin-contracts" (url: Some("https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts"), tag: None)
Installed openzeppelin-contracts v5.0.1

[image]

Comment: I thanks again but the fuzz tests seem to be failing because there is a environment setUp problem so the fuzz test contract can't properly interact with the NFTMarketplace.sol contract, but I can get the environment setUp right, please help.